# Does someone know a text editor which is multi document, support programming languages, images and support RTL languages?

Tags: text-editor, programming

my wet dream of the perfect text editor would be:

Multi documents \ tabs
Programming languages support (indentation, keywords colors, etc.)
RTL languages support (Arabic, Hebrew, etc.)
Accept images
Notepad++ does not support RTL languages and images. It does allow RTL writing but in a very uncomfortable way.

Good old Wordpad support images and RTL, but not multi documents and programming languages. Word does not support programming languages. SublimeText and other programming editors are similar to Notepad++.

Does somebody knows such editor that fullfils all my needs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[Microsoft Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) is the one!

As per your requests:

1. it supports multi documents and tabs
2. performs indentation and keyword colouring
3. has a number of extensions/add-ons which can really enhancing your programming experience
4. supports [RTL Languages](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/use-bidirectional-languages?view=vs-2019) in such a way that languages such as Arabic or Hebrew can be used to name classes, functions, variables, properties, string literals, attributes, and so on. However, the editor does not support right-to-left reading order.
5. works with images